# How do you see result of a Macro before the program compiles

Tags: gcc

I'm compiling a program that uses the `_syscall0` macro.  How do I see the result of this macro before the actual compilation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://oldlinux.org/lxr/http/source/include/unistd.h#L133